# Multiclass classification with random forest in PySpark

Tags: machine-learning, pyspark, random-forest, apache-spark-ml

I have created a RF model which classifies which fare category a train journey falls into based on some basic features such as EntryStation, ExitStation, Day etc as seen in the df below:

[image]

The **features** `Day`, `EntryZone`, `ExitZone`, `ZonalIndicatorKey`, `RouteCode`, `PeakFlag` and `Charge_Profile` are all strings. `EntryStation` and `ExitStation` are `integers`.

The **target variable** (`FareCategory2`) is an integer value where each number represent a monetary banding i.e. 0='0-£1', 1='£1-2' , ... , 9='£9-10', 10='£10+' (there are 11 bandings in total)

How to handle the target variable in this example? Should it be kept as an integer or does it need to be converted to a string? If latter applies, how do I incorporate this into the code below?

```
from pyspark.ml.feature import StringIndexer, VectorAssembler, IndexToString
from pyspark.ml.linalg import Vectors
from pyspark.ml.classification import RandomForestClassifier
from pyspark.ml.evaluation import MulticlassClassificationEvaluator
from pyspark.ml import Pipeline
from pyspark.ml.tuning import CrossValidator,  ParamGridBuilder
import pyspark.sql.functions as F
from pyspark.sql.types import IntegerType



# 1. set features to strings and the target variable (FareCategory2) to an integer
df = df.withColumn("Day", F.col("Day").cast("string"))\
            .withColumn("EntryZone", F.col("EntryZone").cast("string"))\
            .withColumn("ExitZone", F.col("ExitZone").cast("string"))\
            .withColumn("ZonalIndicatorKey", F.col("ZonalIndicatorKey").cast("string"))\
            .withColumn("RouteCode", F.col("RouteCode").cast("string"))\
            .withColumn("PeakFlag", F.col("PeakFlag").cast("string"))\
            .withColumn("CHARGE_PROFILE", F.col("CHARGE_PROFILE").cast("string"))\ 
            .withColumn("FareCategory2", F.col("FareCategory2").cast(IntegerType()))   # this is the TARGET variable


# 2. use StringIndexer to map a string column of labels to a column of label indices
categorical_list = [ "Day", "EntryZone", "ExitZone", "ZonalIndicatorKey", "RouteCode", "PeakFlag", "CHARGE_PROFILE"]   
categoricalCols  = categorical_list 
indexoutputCols  = [x + "_Index" for x in categoricalCols]
stringIndexer    = StringIndexer(inputCols = categoricalCols, outputCols = indexoutputCols, handleInvalid = 'keep')   
numeric_list     = ["EntryStation", "ExitStation"]                                                                                      
numericCols      = numeric_list 
assemblerInputs  = indexoutputCols + numericCols
vecAssembler     = VectorAssembler(inputCols = assemblerInputs, outputCol = 'features')



# 3. create training/test datasets
trainDF, testDF = df.randomSplit([.8,.2], seed = 42)
trainDF.cache()
testDF.cache()



# 4. create rf model 
rf        = RandomForestClassifier(labelCol="FareCategory2", featuresCol="features", numTrees = 20)    
stages    = [stringIndexer, vecAssembler, rf]
pipeline  = Pipeline(stages = stages)
evaluator = MulticlassClassificationEvaluator(labelCol = "FareCategory2", predictionCol = 'prediction', metricName = 'accuracy')
paramGrid = (ParamGridBuilder()
            .addGrid(rf.maxDepth,[2,12])
            .addGrid(rf.numTrees,[5,20])
            .build())
cv        = CrossValidator(estimator          = pipeline, 
                           evaluator          = evaluator,
                           estimatorParamMaps = paramGrid, 
                           numFolds           = 3, 
                           parallelism        = 4, 
                           seed               = 42)


# 5. fit and evaluate model
cvModel     = cv.fit(trainDF)
predictions = cvModel.transform(testDF)
accuracy    = evaluator.evaluate(predictions)
print("Accuracy = %g " % (accuracy))
print("Test error = %g " % (1.0-accuracy))
```